# Simplify `tcpdump` output

Tags: sh, freebsd, tcpdump

I want to convert this `tcpdump` output:

```
IP 10.10.10.1 > 20.20.20.1: ICMP echo request, id 8312, seq 0, length 64
IP 10.10.10.1.17441 > 20.20.20.1.22: Flags [S], seq 3936449810, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,sackOK,TS[|tcp]>
```

to:

```
IP 10.10.10.1 > 20.20.20.1: ICMP
IP 10.10.10.1.17441 > 20.20.20.1.22: tcp
```

I tried a lot to covert them with shell script by using the `cut`command but I can't.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Please include the exact `tcpdump` command that produced the given output.

Comment: You may want to look at [`man sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sed.1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` (or the GNU `gawk`), setting field separator `FS` to ":" and assuming dump is inside test.txt:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ FS=":" } { if($0 ~ / ICMP /){ print $1 ": ICMP" }else if($0 ~ /tcp[]]>/){ print $1 ": tcp" } }' test.txt
```

The expected result:

```
IP 10.10.10.1 > 20.20.20.1: ICMP
IP 10.10.10.1.17441 > 20.20.20.1.22: tcp
```

`tcpdump` output could be piped to `gawk` as

```
tcpdump <options> | gawk ' ... '
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly a `cut` method.  It is assuming your output will always be of this format.  As mentioned, a `sed` (or `awk`) version would probably be more dynamic.

The main piece of this is the `-d` (delimiter) argument and the `-f` (field) argument.  `-f` can specify a single field or range of fields that are separated by a specified delimiter (I believe tabs are default).

If your output is in a file called output.txt, you can use this little script.

```
line1="$(head -1 output.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1-5)"
line2="$(tail -1 output.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1-4) $(tail -1 output.txt | cut -d '|' -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)"

echo "$line1"
echo "$line2"
```

If your output is stored in a variable called output, you could use this script with your 
variable sent as a parameter like `./script.sh "$output"`

```
arg="$1"
line1="$(echo "$arg" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1-5)"
line2="$(echo "$arg" | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f1-4) $(echo "$arg" | tail -1 | cut -d '|' -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)"

echo "$line1"
echo "$line2"
```

Output:

```
IP 10.10.10.1 > 20.20.20.1: ICMP
IP 10.10.10.1.17441 > 20.20.20.1.22: tcp
```